# Two web_view on two activities

Tags: java, android

I just start to learn Android_programming
I want to set two or more links at main_layout and the web_view to another activity (or layout what is easier) so I start this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Context context = this;


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
          @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Web.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }

        });}

public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState){   
final Context context1 = this;
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUrl1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context1, Activity1.class);
        startActivity(i);
      }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: Umm...what's the question? Or problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you have onCreate and onCreate1 ?

```
Button  button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });

        Button  button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Web.class);
                startActivity(intent);
              }

            });
```

Comment: becouse it shows error if is only one onCreate, so i try this

Comment: sorry, i just copy paste your code, now i edited my code, and it's work for me. See the differences?
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
and
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Web.class);

Comment: and just make one onCreate, u dont need 2!